# How to access in octave a variable stored in a .mat binary file?

Tags: matlab, octave, mat

I am accessing the variable from the loaded `.mat` file. This `.mat` file is matlab binary file. The variables contained in this binary file have been generated by a code generator which I have no access to. The variables conform to `class.member` notation.

Octave is successfully able to read this `.mat` file and load the variables into the workspace.

However, when an attempt is made to display the contents of any of these variables, the following error is encountered:

`variable is not defined` error is reflecting.

```matlab
load datafile.mat

w_h1_prev_i = lstm_1.weight_hh;

error : 'lstm_1' undefined`
```

`lstm_1.weight_hh` variable is stored in `datafile.mat`

The question is: How can I get my octave scripts to be able to access these variables in their current format?

Comment: It definitely doesn't exist in that mat-file

Comment: do `clear; load datafile.mat; whos`. The `whos` command shows you all variables in the workspace. You can also try `whos -file datafile.mat` instead. This latter one won't load the file, but show the variables that are in it.

Comment: @Cris Luengo, on execution of `clear; load datafile.mat; whos`. It indicate that the variable `lstm_1.weight_hh` exist but on access  it gives error : `lstm_1 is undefined`.

Comment: That is very weird. Either you have a typo (`l` vs `1` or something like that) or you found a bug in Octave. To make sure you don’t have the former, copy-paste the variable name from the output of `whos`.